# What to do when a question has been asked before but the accepted answer does not contain the answer to the question

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, unanswered-questions

For example, I have the exact same question as asked as the main question in [See all my questions across all Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74222/see-all-my-questions-across-all-stack-exchange-sites#comment179377_74222)

(This question also asks for alternatives as a second question which might be part of the problem, making it look like it has been answered when only this sub question has been answered.)

This means I can no longer ask the same question since it would be a duplicate. However, note that none of the existing answers includes an answer to the main question. (The accepted answer points out you can get a list of the stackexchanges and an individual list for all of them. Other answer tell you how to find a recent subset of questions or highly upvoted questions. No answer lists a method to get all your questions at once.)

It also seems likely that a real answer exists. In a similar (but different) question https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97514/377032 an API that probably has the right capabilities if used correctly is mentioned.

However, there is not really any place for anyone to answer this question or to attract attention to it since the same question has already been asked and an incomplete answer has already been accepted.

What should I do in such a case?

Comment: Your question seems to relate to Meta Stack Exchange rather than Meta GIS SE so I'm unsure why you have asked this here rather than there.  In any event, I think the same principles apply.

Comment: Oops, I thought I was on Meta Stack Exchange. I don't know how I ended up here. (It is not an exact duplicate btw because that question does not seem to be about questions that already have an accepted wrong answer.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [bounty system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) to draw attention to the question. Once you place a bounty, you can add a personalized message specifying any feature of the question that you wish to highlight or what you would like to see in an answer.